# class not found exception while adding validator class

Tags: validation, jsf, exception

0 with eclipse and glassfish, in fact i have added a  custom validator to validate emai address, and i am getting class not found exception. although i have registered in faces.config too.

here is my validator code

```
public static final String EmailPattern= "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\." +
            "[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*" +
            "(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
   public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
        if(!matcher.matches())
        {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Please enter a valid email address");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }
```

i registerd in faces.config

```
<validator>

<validator-id>emailvalidator</validator-id>
<validator-class>com.jsf.validators.EmailValidator</validator-class>
</validator>
```

does someone know what is the problem in it.

Comment: This could just be your IDE integrated servlet container is out of sync with your project.  Try doing a clean and rebuild before publishing your project.  Then you should inspect the servlet container deployment directory for the missing class file to verify that it exists.

Comment: The complete stacktrace would also be helpful to confirm if you're really understanding the concrete problem. **Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please carefully review if your email regex fits in the World Domination plans of your website. You're namely blocking all non-latin users such as Cyrillic, Hebrew, Sanskrit, Chinese, Japanese, etc. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address/1931322#1931322

Comment: @maple_shaft thanx for reply, i have cleaned and rebuilt it, it is working fine now.

Comment: @BalusC thanx for the link you mentioned it is really helpful.